# Array-within-array items replacement

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, xcode

I have a list of arrays, each of elements of these is array to. I know, it's a little freaky, but it's necessary. So, I need to replace elements of deepest array. I've tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] count]; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < [[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] count]; k++) {
            [[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] replaceObjectAtIndex:k withObject:@"Some_string"];
        }
    }
}
```

and got an error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. But I can to log this element, e.g. `NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0]objectAtIndex:0]]);`, it's ok.

What it can be? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your arrays instances of `NSMutableArray` instead of immutable `NSArray`?

Comment: Yes. I should convert it to NSMutableArray? UPDATE: I create mutable array from myArray by `NSMutableArray *myMutArray = [myArray mutableCopy]`, but it doesn't helps.

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to have the inner arrays mutable. So instead of [myArray mutableCopy] do `myMutArray = [NSMutableArray array]`, then go through myArray and add, for each subarray, its mutableCopy to the new `myMutArray`.

Comment: Sorry, little misunderstanding. `myArray` is instance of NSArray initially. @mrueg, ok, thanks, I'll try.

Comment: @mrueg `mutableCopy` is guaranteed to return a mutable instance.